# How to escape the quotes in JSON Object?

Tags: java, gson, json

Below is my method which makes the `JSONObject` and then print out the `JSONString`.

I am using Google GSON.

```
private String generateData(ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> dataTable, int i) {

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    Set<Integer> ap = dataTable.get("TEST1").get(i);
    Set<Integer> bp = dataTable.get("TEST2").get(i);

    jsonObject.addProperty("description", "test data");
    jsonObject.addProperty("ap", ap.toString());
    jsonObject.addProperty("bp", bp.toString());

    System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

Currently if I print out the  `jsonObject.toString()` then it prints out like this -

```
{"description":"test data","ap":"[0, 1100, 4, 1096]","bp":"[1101, 3, 6, 1098]"}
```

But this is not what I need. I want to print out like below which is without double quote on `ap` and `bp` values.

```
{"description":"test data","ap":[0, 1100, 4, 1096],"bp":[1101, 3, 6, 1098]}
```

I am not sure how do I escape that quotes in the JSONObject?

Comment: Culprit is `jsonObject.addProperty("ap", ap.toString())`. You have already converted the array into string representation! Instead add it as a JSON array. That will fix the problem.

Comment: @RaviH: Can you show an example how would I do that? It doesn't work with `toArray` as well.

Comment: @Sotirios Your right I was thinking of gson.toJson(someSet);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that with

```
jsonObject.addProperty("ap", ap.toString());
```

you are adding a property which is the `String` representation of a `Set` in Java. It has nothing to do with JSON (even if the format looks the same).

You will have to convert your `Set` into a `JsonElement` (a `JsonArray` really but you won't see that).

Create a `Gson` object somewhere

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

and use it to convert your `Set` elements to `JsonElement` objects and add them to the `JsonObject`.

```
jsonObject.add("ap", gson.toJsonTree(ap));
jsonObject.add("bp", gson.toJsonTree(bp));
```

Gson has its conventions, it converts a `Set` into a `JsonArray` which is a sub type of `JsonElement` and you can therefore add it with `JsonObject#add(String, JsonElement)`.

Comment: It doesn't work as well. `The method addProperty(String, String) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, JsonElement)`

Comment: @SSH `add` not `addProperty`.

Comment: @SSH Try not to create a `Gson` object in the method. It will slow everything down as it's a quite heavy initialization. Either pass it as a method argument or reference it with a `static` variable somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Android Platform 23 then you shall able to use org.json.JSONObject instead:

```
private String generateData(ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>> dataTable, int i) {
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
try {
    JSONArray apArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Integer i : ap) {
        apArray.put(i.intValue());
    }
    JSONArray bpArray = new JSONArray();
    for (Integer i : bp) {
        bpArray.put(i.intValue());
    }

    jsonObject.put("description", "test data");

    jsonObject.put("ap", apArray);
    jsonObject.put("bp", bpArray);
    Log.d("Json string", jsonObject.toString());
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("JSONException",e.getMessage());
}

System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringEscapeUtils:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

(...)

myString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson(myString);
```

On Android, remember to update your app/build.gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try regex if you really need a string...

```
string.replace(new RegExp('("\\[)', 'g'), '[').replace(new RegExp('(\\]")', 'g'), ']')
```

Better explained, "[ is replaced with [ and ]" is replaced with ]

### Question was not his method of working with the JSON Object, it was how to escape array quotes.

Comment: The quotes were a misunderstanding of what they were adding to the Json object. They wanted a Json array instead of a String which is the `toString()` result of a `Set`. See the expected JSON.

Comment: Looks like this is the only solution. Only thing we need to change the syntax for android.