# Creating Map or Set using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, couchbase

I am using Google's GSON library and want to create a JSON which looks something like this:

```
{
 "teamSet":[],
 "classificationMap" : {}
}
```

Notice that [] and {} are empty Set and Map respectively and are not surrounded with double quotes.

**I want to create this Json using the GSON add/addproperty method** and not by converting a Java class into JSON using the Gson.toJson() method. The business use-case restricts me from creating specific Java classes as the JSON structure may change overtime. So I cannot use a class like this as this would rigidly tie a JSON structure with a concrete class

```
class Linkage{
 private Set<String> teamSet;
 private Map<String, String> classificationMap;

 // getter, setter methods follow 
 ...
}
```

When I use the  GSON.addproperty(genericObject, type), it is appending double quotes around [] and {}. I am using couchbase for my DB requirements and the double quotes around [] and {} makes couchbase treat them as string and not as Set/Map. This renders my Map-Reduce views useless and buggy :(

Please let me know if its possible to create such a JSON without having to tie it up with a concrete JAVA class. Thanks !

My current code looks like this:

```
// create types
Type setType = new TypeToken<Set<String>>() {}.getType();
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {}.getType();

Gson GSON = new Gson();

Set<String> teams = new HashSet<String>();
Map<String, String> classificationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

JsonObject linkageJson = new JsonObject();
linkageJson.addProperty("teamSet", GSON.toJson(teams, setType));
linkageJson.addProperty("classificationMap", GSON.toJson(classificationMap, mapType));
```

Comment: please post the code how you are adding the set and map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i feel somewhere it is storing it **toString()** representation.

Please refer below link, it might help you.

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949674/how-to-escape-the-quotes-in-json-object)

Comment: I used toJsonTree() method as mentioned in the link and it works awaesome. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the 2.x line of the couchbase java sdk, there is the `JsonObject` class that could have fit your need.

It is perfect to create Json "by hand" and still have a simple generic object representation, and is the official way of putting json into the database via the sdk.

It would go like this :

```
JsonObject obj = JsonObject.create();
obj.put("teamSet", JsonArray.from(new ArrayList(teams)))
   .put("classificationMap", JsonObject.from(classificationMap));
```

Granted this is a little bit contrived because arrays and sub-objects can only be constructed from respectively `List<?>` and `Map<String, ?>` factory methods. Also the class support a limited set of value types (no custom classes, only String, Number, Boolean, etc...).