# JAVA create Json array without quotation marks

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a nested json and one of its elements is an integer array.

I would like to get output like this:

`{ "arguments" : [ { "array": [1, 2, 3] } ] }`

but I keep receiving array in quotes like this:

`{ "arguments" : [ { "array" : "[1, 2, 3]" } ] }`

Here is my code:

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArrayBuilder;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonArrayBuilder arguments = Json.createArrayBuilder().add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("array", Arrays.toString(new int[] {1,2,3})));
        String json = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("arguments", arguments).build().toString();
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

EDIT

Thanks to  Jon Skeet, I managed to do this

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
JsonArrayBuilder arrayBuilder = Json.createArrayBuilder();
for (int i : ints) {
        arrayBuilder.add(i);
}
JsonArrayBuilder arguments = 
Json.createArrayBuilder().add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("array", arrayBuilder.build()));
```

Although i thought there may be a better looking way,
thanks

Comment: You're passing in the builder. Try calling `build()` first.

Comment: and why do you want this? you are aware that you're risking ending up with invalid json, right?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(new int[] {1,2,3})` will do that for you - try something else.

Comment: Hint: you're creating an array builder, but only calling `add` once. That will create an array with one element. You want an array with three elements, so you need to call `add` three times.

Comment: Similar Problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949674/how-to-escape-the-quotes-in-json-object

Comment: Stultuske, both are valid, unfortunately, the choice of json does not depend on me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding an object named "array", and telling object builder that it is a string:

```
Arrays.toString(new int[] {1,2,3})
```

You are passing a string here, how do You expect object builder to know it is supposed to be a collection not string? Its just a dumb VM, if it sees string it considers it a string, even though the string is a string version of array. If the VM sees a string "ferrari" it still thinks its a string not a real ferrari right? ;)

What You want to do is on the righthandside, Instead of Arrays.toString create another array builder, and add all your int objects one by one to it and add that resulting object instead of "Arrays.toString(new int[] {1,2,3})" More or less like this:

```
JsonArrayBuilder arguments = Json.createArrayBuilder().add(Json.createObjectBuilder().add("array", Json.createArrayBuilder().add(1).add(2).add(3))));
```

Comment: Obviously you would put that whole thing in a method that does it automatically, don't inline and hardcode your data into the code :P

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful I hope that the OP understands that, and his code was only of showcase purpose